# Django problem with validating forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have been trying to figure out how all this validation works, but I am not getting the hang of it. I read the very few examples on djangoproject, but I am missing concepts and how everything is tied together.

If you could please look at my code and rearrange how things should be, as well as a few explanations, that would be awesome!

So I want to do something very simple: have a login from with email ONLY. When a user types their email, i want to check if it's in the database, and if it is, login. if it is not, i want to raise an error 'user already in database' and suggest that this person goes to /register

So what i currently have is:

**view.py:**

```
def emailLogin(request, backend, extra_context=None, initial={}):

form = EmailLoginForm(initial=initial)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EmailLoginForm(initial=initial, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.do_save()

        _no_pass_login(request, user) # my custom login
        return redirect('/')

    else:
        print ('not valid')

return render_jinja(request, 'registration/email_login_form.html',
        type="register",
        form = form
        )
```

**forms.py**:

```
class EmailLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    def do_save(self):
    try:
            u = User.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        except :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Already in DB")

        return u
```

So the whole point is that I am missing concepts - where should a validation error be raised, the view or the form? where is it raised to? who catches it? what needs to be imported in each file etc.

This shouldn't be too difficult but i am totally lost now, and i have no examples I can analyze and mod my code to work, so i am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do seem to be missing some concepts.

This type of form shouldn't have a save at all. And the whole point of the `is_valid()` check is to catch the validation errors - so they should be raised by that call. The way to do that is to define `clean` methods on the form. In this case, since you're only checking the `email` field, you define a `clean_email` method. The code should be identical to what you've currently got in `do_save`.

Now, `is_valid()` will return False. But there are a couple of tweaks needed in your view to actually show the errors. First, bring that `else` block *back* one indent level, so it matches `if request.method == 'POST'`. Now, instead of that `print` statement, move the first line - `form = EmailLoginForm(initial=initial)` in there. Now, when `is_valid()` is False, the view will fall straight through to the render_to_response with an already-instantiated form containing the validation errors. Magic!

Comment: is the method name related to the field name, or can i use `def clean_myemailfunction(self):` ?

Comment: I think his code will fall through to render_to_response() when the form is not valid already (with the instantiated form and errors). So I don't think your 2nd paragraph is necessary. I agree with your advice in the 1st paragraph.

Comment: @mgPePe you have to use `clean_<fieldname>`. This is all in the documentation on [validating forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: @Brian true, but it's always best to recommend good practice. In this case, the OP is instantiating the form twice for a POST, unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanx, and just for reference, shouldn't the form return an email instead of user? Isn't it more 'good practice'. I imagine I should be doing `return self.cleaned_data['email']`.

Comment: Well, whatever is returned from there is put into `cleaned_data` for that field. So it's quite valid to return the user, if that's what you want. But yes, normally you would return the field value.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, I missed the double form instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what Daniel was talking about, but it can be confusing if you don't know exactly what's going on. Basically, all the form  does is validate your data. All the saving is done in the view.

**view.py**

```
def emailLogin(request, backend, extra_context=None, initial={}):

    form = EmailLoginForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form(initial=initial, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            _no_pass_login(request, user) # my custom login
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print 'Form not valid'

    else:
        form = form(initial=initial)

return render_jinja(request, 'registration/email_login_form.html',
    type="register",
    form = form
    )
```

**forms.py**

```
class EmailLoginForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError('User with email "%s" already exists' % email)
        return email
```

Comment: Not quite - the `clean_email` method should return `email`, not the whole dictionary.

Comment: Good catch. How does the rest look?